# Denominator in t Test formula for 2 independent samples

Tags: mathematical-statistics, t-test

If we want to make a 2 independent sample t test we need to calculate the following test statistic:

$$T = \frac{\overline X - \overline Y}{\sqrt{\frac{S^{2}}{n}+ \frac{S^{2}}{m}}}$$
where

$$S^{2} = \frac{(n-1)\cdot S^{2}_X + (m-1)\cdot S^{2}_Y}{n+m-2}$$

Well as I understand, $S^2$ it is the weighted mean of both sample variances. Why do we add those variances and divide by n and m in the denominator of T, though? We already added Variances of X and Y, and we divided by the corresponding degrees of freedom.

So, what’s the point? Or in other words: Why not use this $T$:

$$T = \frac{\overline X - \overline Y}{\sqrt{S^2 }}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, the denominator is assumed to be an approximation to the deviation of the *mean difference*. For example, if it wasn't pooled variance, (assuming independence)  $$\operatorname{var}(\bar X-\bar Y)=\operatorname{var}(\bar X)+\operatorname{var}(\bar Y)=\frac{\sigma_x^2}{n}+\frac{\sigma_y^2}{m}\approx \frac{S_x^2}{n}+\frac{S_y^2}{m}$$

If we assume $X$ and $Y$ have equal variances, and use the pooled sample variance as the estimate for their variances, we'll have $S_x^2\approx S_y^2\approx S_p^2$. And, the formula above makes sense.